# Transform QLSTM model output expectation values back into classical data

Tags: quantum-state, machine-learning

What is the typical procedure for transforming a model's expvals back into the classical data format? I'm new to QML and need some insight.

I have some expvals that were the output of model i.e. `[0.60226303 2.29067277 0.87645921 2.29067277 0.87645921]`, I would like to turn these back into classical data to evaluate the predictive performance of the model in addition to the received cost function measurements.

Prior to the variational circuit routine the classical data was normalized using the following padding and normalization steps before applying a state preparation function that computes the angles for the input:

```python
# Load the pH features data (x)
data_features = data_features_df_txt

# Pad the vectors constant values
features_padding = np.ones((len(data_features), 5)) * 0.1
data_features_padding = np.c_[data_features, features_padding]`

# Normalize each input
normalization = np.sqrt(np.sum(data_features_padding**2, -1))
data_features_norm = (data_features_padding.T / normalization).T'

# Obtain the final state preparation features by applying the get_angles function
features = np.array([get_angles(feat) for feat in data_features_norm], requires_grad=False)
```

```python
# Get_angles function
def get_angles(x):
    beta0 = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(x[1] ** 2) / np.sqrt(x[0] ** 2 + x[1] ** 2 + 1e-12))
    beta1 = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(x[2] ** 2) / np.sqrt(x[2] ** 2 + x[2] ** 2 + 1e-12))
    beta2 = 2 * np.arcsin(np.linalg.norm(x[2:]) / np.linalg.norm(x))
    
    return np.array([beta2, -beta1 / 2, beta1 / 2, -beta0 / 2, beta0 / 2])
```

I've tried reversing the get angles function but have come to a standstill with regards to how to de-normalize the result from the reversal and retracing the data back from the normalization and padding operations.

Any guidance here is greatly appreciated.